# Creating an Array of JSON Objects of Dynamically Created Fields using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here are the Dynamically generated Fields. For sort of Simplicity, I have removed unnecessary codes
Please help me to generate an Array of JSON Object when I click on a button

```
<div class="row sertile">
                          
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control parType" value="Service">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control id" value="144">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control serviceName" value="Full face">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control mrp" value="200">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control dis" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control dur" value="30">

  </div>

<div class="row sertile">
                          
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control parType" value="Service">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control id" value="124">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control serviceName" value="Half face">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control mrp" value="200">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control dis" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control dur" value="30">

  </div>
```

I need output as:

```
[
 {
  parType: 'Service', 
  id: 144,
  serviceName: 'Full Face',
  ...
 }, 
 {
  parType: 'Service', 
  id: 124,
  serviceName: 'Half Face',
  ...
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have got the idea how to solve it.

Comment: Note that that HTML is invalid. You can't have the same ID on multiple elements. Use a class instead.

Comment: Yes, elements already have the class not id.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to tackle this. Thank you all for your help.

```
        function createJSON() {
          jsonObj = [];
          $(".sertile").each(function() {

            var id = $(this).find("#serId").val();
            var name = $(this).find("#serName").val();

            item = {}
            item["title"] = id;
            item["email"] = name;

            jsonObj.push(item);
          });

          console.log(jsonObj);
        }
```

Comment: Yup -- but beware that code is creating what I call an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare `jsonObj`. Also, since it's not JSON, I suggest not calling it `jsonObj`. Finally, you can also use `map` to do this: `const result = $(".sertile").get().map(element => ( const title = $(element).find(".serId").val(); const email = $(element).find(".serName").val(); return {title, email};);` (I've used class selectors there, not ID selectors, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70110049/?#comment123936057_70110049).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your valuable information. Your details really helped me to do things in the correct manner. Thank you so much, brother. ))

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [Element.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) ?

An idea might be to add a tag to your div and to get them by `getElementsByClassName` on the document,
then to loop over them to get each field by it's class and to add it to an object that you can then convert to string json if you need to

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, he could try to use Element.getElementsByClassName(), but if he never used or do not know how it works, how can he implement it? You should provide a simple example so the person who asked know how to implement, or at least have a better start point